# Erasing while traversing in C++ stl map giving runtime error

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, stdmap

Following lines of C++ code gives runtime error but if erase operation `mymap.erase(v)` is removed it works:

```
map<int,int> mymap = {{1,0},{2,1},{9,2},{10,3},{11,4}};
for(auto it=mymap.rbegin();it!=mymap.rend();){
    int v=it->first;
    ++it;
    mymap.erase(v);
}
```

[demo](https://ideone.com/RB9zgz)

Here iterator `it` is changed before deleting its value `v`, so iterator `it` should remain unaffected I believe.

Comment: works for me, see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea08f4df34c6bbf0), can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Fails for me: https://ideone.com/MVpW8S

Comment: @Thomas Here you go [link](https://ideone.com/RB9zgz) .  I used     map<int,int> mymap={{1,0},{2,1},{9,2},{10,3},{11,4}};

Comment: @user4581301 You dereferenced `mymap.rend()`

Comment: Instead of adding a demo as a comment, in the future, just edit the post to include it. I've done it this time.

Comment: @Paul That would happen, but the  program didn't get that far. Could be time-travelling UB though. Same fatality without the print statements: https://ideone.com/o2FLkR

Comment: I think the problem is with the reverse iterator, it works ok when using begin/end rather than rbegin/rend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you are calling `erase(v)`, you are invalidating the *base* `iterator` that the next `reverse_iterator` (from `++it`) is using.  So you need to create a new `reverse_iterator` from the base `iterator` that precedes the erased value.

Also, rather than erasing the *value* that the `reverse_iterator` is referring to, you should erase the base `iterator` instead, since you already know which element you want to erase. There is no need to make the `map` go hunting for the value again.

This works for me:

```cpp
map<int,int> mymap = {{1,0},{2,1},{9,2},{10,3},{11,4}};
for(auto it = mymap.rbegin(); it != mymap.rend(); ){
    auto v = --(it.base());
    v = mymap.erase(v);
    it = map<int,int>::reverse_iterator(v);
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Hqtc0J)

On the other hand, this loop is essentially just `erase()`'ing all elements from `mymap`, so a better option is to use [`mymap.clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/clear) instead.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, [`std::map::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator):

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.

But [`std::reverse_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator)

> For a reverse iterator r constructed from an iterator i, the relationship `&*r == &*(i-1)` is always true (as long as r is dereferenceable); thus a reverse iterator constructed from a one-past-the-end iterator dereferences to the last element in a sequence.

Perhaps it gets more clear when you look at the image on the cppreference page.

[image]

The crucial part is "Reverse iterator stores an iterator to the next element than the one it actually refers to".

As a consequence (small modification to your code)

```
auto& element = *it;       // fails in the next iteration, because...
int v = element.first;
++it;                      // now it stores an iterator to element
mymap.erase(v);            // iterators to element are invalidated
```

You are erasing the element that is used by `it` in the next iteration.

Comment: "*there is literally no difference to going forwards*" - and technically, this loop is just `erase()`'ing all elements from the `map`, so a better option is `mymap.clear()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I actually did not realize that :)

Comment: Still runtime error [link](https://ideone.com/jZPdtp) . This other solution by RemyLebeau is correct. I don't think your modification changes anything . Variable v still contains same value . Thank you for the effort though I did not know these things about reverse iterators.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The context is quite complicated I just posted my specific problem . I had to erase some elements in reverse order

Comment: @PratapSingh the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) is usually your bestest of friends when you find yourself erasing while iterating.

Comment: @PratapSingh this answer only explains the problem, the modification is to demonstrate it in smaller terms. But there is no fix offered, which is why your code still has a runtime error.

Comment: @PratapSingh usually I am the one complaining that comments are not good to get some message across. My modifications were not supposed to change anything.